# Swift - Cannot find an overload for 'init' and 'round'

Tags: swift

I've been trying to make something to generate questions for some of my third grade students, but I keep running into the "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments" and "Cannot find an overload for 'round' that accepts an argument list of type '(Int)'".  I'm completely new to Swift and I've been Googling around for the last hour or so.

I know it's not the most elegant thing to look at, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class Question {

var player: Player
var question: String
var answer: Int = 0
var gradeThreeAdditionBank:[String] = ["Hello","Goodbye"]
var gradeThreeSubtractionBank:[String] = ["Hello"]
var gradeThreeMultiplicationBank:[String] = ["Hello"]
var gradeThreeDivisionBank:[String] = ["Hello"]
var gradeThreeRoundingBank:[String] = ["Round the following to the nearest rnd.factors: ", "rnd.name needs around rnd.number rnd.item(s).  About how many does s/he need? (Round to the nearest rnd.factors.)"]
var gradeThreeRoundingFactors:[String] = ["one", "ten", "hundred"]
var gradeThreeFractionBank:[String] = ["Hello"]
var gradeThreeMultiStepBank:[String] = ["Hello"]

var randomName:[String] = ["Brayden", "Justin", "Nelson", "Ryan", "Russell", "Albert", "Adam", "Yan Bo", "Jonathan", "Chris", "Michael", "Alan", "Nicholas", "Brian", "Jeremy", "Max", "William", "Victor", "Ethan", "Johnny", "Terry", "Liam", "Selina", "Althea", "Amber", "Morgan", "Emma", "Kelly", "Kaitlyn", "Ashley", "Patience", "Brianna", "Jessica", "Lilian", "Charlotte", "Tiffany", "Nancy", "Crystal", "Lily", "Winnie", "Sarah", "Doris"]

init(question:String, answer:Int, player:Player) {
    self.question = question
    self.answer = answer
    self.player = player
}

func generateQuestion() -> (String, Int) {
    var questionType:String = ""

    if (player.getLevel() >= 1 && player.getLevel() < 5) {
        //(question, answer) = generateGradeThreeRoundingBank()
    }
    else if (player.getLevel() == 5) {

    }

    return (question, answer)
}


func generateGradeThreeRoundingBank() -> (String, Int) {
    // Chooses the question type
    var tempType:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))
    // Generates the text for the selected question type
    var temp:String = gradeThreeRoundingBank[tempType]
    // Generates a random number to round
    var tempNumb = Int(arc4random_uniform(990)) + 10
    // Chooses a factor to round to
    var roundTo:String = gradeThreeRoundingFactors[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))]
    if (tempNumb < 100) {
        roundTo = gradeThreeRoundingFactors[Int(arc4random_uniform(2))]
    }
    else if (tempNumb < 10) {
        roundTo = "one"
    }
    else {
        roundTo = gradeThreeRoundingFactors[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))]
    }
    // Saves an Int version of roundTo
    var roundToNumber:Int = 0
    if (roundTo == "one") {
        roundToNumber = 1
    } else if (roundTo == "ten") {
        roundToNumber = 10
    } else {
        roundToNumber = 100
    }
    // Generates an answer based on retrieved information
    var tempAnswer = 0
    if (roundToNumber == 1) {
        tempAnswer = Int(round(tempNumb))
    } else if (roundToNumber == 10) {
        tempAnswer = Int(round(tempNumb)/10) * 10
    } else {
        tempAnswer = Int(round(tempNumb)/100) * 100
    }
    // Generates a question using the bank and replacing values with retrieved values
    if (tempType == 0) {
        temp.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("rnd.factor", withString: roundTo)
        temp.append(round(tempNumb))
    }
    else if (tempType == 1) {
        temp.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("rnd.factor", withString: roundTo)
    }
    return (temp, tempAnswer)
}
```

}

Comment: `round` takes a `Float` or `Double`.  Why are you trying to round an `Int`?

Comment: Please make your code shorter and only show what is relevant to your question. Im not going to look throught your whole file for it.

Comment: At the very least mark your code to show the lines that are giving you errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is picky about its data types.  Here, you have created `tempNumb` to be of type `Int`:

```
var tempNumb = Int(arc4random_uniform(990)) + 10
```

Later, when you call:

```
    tempAnswer = Int(round(tempNumb))
```

you get the error message telling you that `round()` doesn't take an `Int`, because it doesn't.  `round()` takes a `Double` or a `Float`.

So perhaps you want to start with a `Double`:

```
var tempNumb = Double(arc4random_uniform(990) + 10)
```

---

Helpful hint:  Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and click on any variable to find its type.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed all the variables to Doubles and casted to Int when necessary later on instead and there's not a red dot in sight.